# How do I make an array of objects light up sequentially?

Tags: modifiers, light, keyframes, loop

I have many cylinders duplicated with an array.
The material emits light.
I need to make the cylinders light up and turn off one after an other in a loop.
Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Related: [How to control many tiny lights](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47375/how-to-control-many-tiny-lights/47385#47385)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94699/animating-running-lights https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121629/how-would-one-animate-blinking-lights-in-viewport-opengl-render https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73792/light-blinking-objects-in-cycles-render

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since the array is an exact copy of the first object, I don't think there is a way to do what I understand you wanna do. What I suggest is copying the object with array (to keep it in case), then apply the array.

Without separating your object and materials, you can animate the light changes with a texture that, depending of the UV, will either light up or not your objects only by keyframing the texture coordinate. So UV unwrap all your cylinders from the front: [image]

Then you have to make a texture that looks like that:
[image]

Finally in your material, set it up a bit like that and move the X value of the mapping node to align the white part of the texture over the cylinder you want to light up:
[image]

[image]

OR you can always have multiple objects with different material that are animated independently (probably more time consuming).

Comment: Thank you! I ended up just keeping them in the array and adding a driver to the mapping x axis, making the white square jump every ten frames. in my case: 0.2+0.25*int(frame/10)

Comment: @3ifdj30 - if this answer helped you, please do not post "Thank you" comments, instead [mark it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I could be way off but once you apply the array modifier, I believe you'd manually have to key frame the emission strength per copy of the cylinder. I'm curious what others recommend.